# Hibernate unidirectional mapping on two fields

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a Creature class and Item Class:

I need unidirectional mapping in Creature as follows:

```
@Entity
public  class Creature {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> equippedItems;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> itemsInBackpack;

    //getters/setters
}
```

Hibernate creates additional table:

| Creature_id | itemsInBackpack_id | equippedItems_id |

This is fine for me. But the problem is that both itemsInBackpack_id and equippedItems_id have nullable set to false. This causes the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'itemsInBackpack_id' doesn't have a default value
```

How to tell Hibernate to allow null values on those columns?

Edit:

this is how I save it:

```
Item item1 = new Item();
Item item2 = new Item();

creature.getEquippedItems().add(item1);
creature.getItemsInBackpack().add(item2);

repository.save(creature);
```

Edit

Item class:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

What I want to achieve: Item can be only in backpack or equipped. Not Both.

Comment: Can you show us both Creature and Item full code?

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. If an id value is nullable, then Hibernate won't be able to reference the row of the `Item` table that contains your item. 

I think what you want to try is to set the `id` on `Item` to be generated. Then when you call `new Item()` it will have an `id` and can be inserted.

`@Entity    
public class Item {    

 @Id    
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
 @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)    
 private Long id;     

}`

Comment: What I want to achieve: Item can be only in backpack or equipped. Not Both.I've updated the question.

Comment: Maybe then modify the setters to remove the item from the other list when it's added.

Comment: @Yserbius I can't even save it because when item is inserted to one collection, then the second column is null. Please re-read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably going to want to make two separate mapping tables. You can get control over your tables with the [`@JoinTable` annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html). So modify the code for `Creature` to me something like

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="CREATURE_EQUIPPED_ITEM")
private List<Item> equippedItems;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="CREATURE_INVENTORY_ITEM")
private List<Item> itemsInBackpack;
```

This will create two separate tables so you shouldn't have to worry about a column being null. A better way to do it may be to have an "itemEquipped" flag table, something like:

```
@Entity
public class EquippableItem{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;

    @Column
    private boolean isEquipped;

    @Column 
    private Item item;


    //getters and setters
}
```

Then instead of two `Item` lists for your creature, you can just have one `EquippableItem` list.

Comment: The first solution with @JoinTable is exactly what I needed. Thanks!.

Comment: Second solution may be also good, but for my needs I'll prefer the first one :)